# How do I curve a textbox on the lower part of a circle without the text having to be upside down, in Illustrator CC?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, text-on-path

I used the "type on a path" to make a curved textbox on the top of a circle but when I want to have the text curved on the lower part of the circle it has to be upside down.. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can type on the other side of the path (inside the circle). If I remember correctly you can just drag the curser to the other side of the path.

Answer (score 2):

Use the 'type on path' tool to type out your words on the circle, then while you have that circular type selected with the selection tool, double-click the 'type on path' tool to pull up the 'type on path' options dialog box. There you will see a dropdown menu and a checkbox. Check the box to invert the text (something like that), then play around with the 'ascender/baseline/etc.' options in the dropdown menu to get the text on the outside/inside/etc. of your circle.